# Is it possible to make a Remote Desktop connection private from people physically watching the screen?

Tags: desktop, remote-desktop, privacy, vnc

When I use VNC or RDP to remotely control my office computer, as far as I'm aware, someone standing in front of my computer could be seeing everything I'm doing. Furthermore, if I lose my connection then the computer will still be logged in (i.e. not locked) so someone in my office could do whatever they wanted with my login credentials.

Is there a way to remotely access ones machine that doesn't compromise privacy from someone who may be physically in front of the machine?

Comment: I think this question belong to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) rather than SO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use Xvnc to create a virtual session.

Alternatively, to secure access to the console session, set an idle timeout on the connection and configure the server to lock the session when the last client disconnects. That way, if you do disconnect, it won't be a problem.